How do I get rid of extra space in cell when using Text Wrap in Excel for Mac 2016?
I am using Excel to make a table with several columns with word wrapped text. When using auto cell height there is some extra space at the bottom of each cell - successively larger space for every line of text in the cell. When printing, the blank space becomes even larger than on the screen. No WYSIWYG. Haven’t found any way to get rid of the space except manually adjusting the height of each row.
Tried different fonts, taken away the text wrap and resized the column and then tried auto height again with no success. The % view does not make any difference.
Tried moving the file to excel in Windows. Same problem there.

Are there any carriage returns at the end of the cells in question?

No, there are no carrage returns at the end. It’s not like extra lines in some cells but more like successivly larger space when more lines of rext in the cells
